# Struts2 html checkbox not pre-checked

Tags: html, jsp, checkbox, struts2

```
<body>
    <h3>Register for a prize by completing this form.</h3>
    <s:form action="register">
          <s:textfield name="personBean.firstName" label="First name" />
          <s:textfield  name="personBean.lastName" label="Last name" />
          <s:textfield name="personBean.email"  label ="Email"/>
          <s:textfield name="personBean.age"  label="Age"  />
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
          <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
</body>
```

I have a jsp with above content. The checkbox within the form is not checked whereas the checkbox outside form is pre-checked. I am mixing up plain html checkbox and non-html elements within a Struts2 form.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have malformed html by putting input tag like that in your form.

To resolve it,you can use **s:checkbox**

```
<s:checkbox name="checkMe" fieldValue="true" label="Check Me for testing" value="true"/>
```

Comment: You have malformed html. That is why checked isn't working.

Comment: Thanks  Aleksandr M for pointing it out.I was not aware about this.
I just thought its weird to put something into table like this.

Comment: Now, when you know why it isn't working you can give a proper answer.